Any difference between storing data in an ReplaySubject or passing it back to resolver to store?
In Angular 18, I see you pass the data back to the resolver and the page can load the data.  However, on 'MOST' all calls, something like this is going on storing the data into something like a ReplaySubject or other ->
    async fetch(): Promise<UserData> {
        const email = this._singleModel.getUserEmail();
        const request = new FetchUserRequest();
        request.email = email;
        const response = await this._baseClient.fetchUser(request);
        const userData = convert(response.user);
        this.setUser(userData);

        return userData;
    }

setUser calls this._user.next(value); and _user is declared like so
    private _user: ReplaySubject<UserData> = new ReplaySubject<UserData>(1);

I find the storage of the data into ReplaySubject MOST useful where as my application evolves, I can tie any new components to read from there if things change.  Returning any data to the resolver for the resolver to store feels a bit off, BUT I am probably missing something and so my question exists.  Do I let the resolver store state or do I store the state?
I also prefer the strong typed this.setUser(data) vs. returning to a resolver.
I am thinking of having my resolver just look like this in every case
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UserResolverService implements Resolve<any> {
    private _userService = inject(UserService);

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
        const promise = this._userService.fetch().then((res) => { return null; });
        return from(promise); //convert promise to observable
    }
}

I tried the above things.

I don't believe the resolver is "storing" anything. Its purpose is to ensure that the data needed by a component/route is loaded before the component is rendered. Nothing wrong with needing to access a service to achieve that goal, so your approach looks typical to me - the service knows how to fetch data, the resolver is responsible for calling the service during routing. Caching/memoizing the result in the service is (probably) a performance step, not related to the nature of the service or the resolver. tl;dr - you're doing it right, but confusing memoization and the role of the resolver.

@DM then why is the signature Observable and not Observable. I read about some way to fetch the data after you returned the data back through that method but instead opted to just read from the service Observable instead(At least I thought I did).

Good question, I have no idea. Returning an observable makes since (so we can tell when the resolver has finished), but none of the patterns I can find documentation about use this value. Maybe the team has some internal use? Logging, for example? Or maybe they just left their options open since Observable<void> and Observable<never> are so restrictive.
